# What is the benefit of having a fixed target block interval?

Tags: consensus, block-interval

By design Bitcoin targets a block interval of 10 minutes.

How does the blockchain benefit from maintaining a bounded block time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was the target block time chosen to be 10 minutes?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/why-was-the-target-block-time-chosen-to-be-10-minutes)

Comment: I am more worried about why the time is fixed, not specifically why it is 10 min?

Answer (score 1):

Block mining time [is not fixed](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_soon_might_I_expect_to_generate_a_block.3F). 10 minutes is just average value which is aimed by [difficulty adjustment algorithm](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) to balance two contradicting requirements:

1. low transaction time requires low block mining time.
2. low probability to mine several different blocks simultaneously requires higher block mining time.