# How could block propagation time be reduced?

Tags: block, network, latency, block-propagation-time

[This website measures block and transaction time propagation.](http://bitcoinstats.com/network/propagation/). At the time of writing, the time required for 90% of surveyed clients to get a block is about twelve seconds. (I just averaged the last five days.)

How could this be reduced? On a related note, what are the major causes of propagation delay? Is this primarily caused by **network latency**, **network bandwidth**, or by clients **verifying the block**?

Related:

- [How long does it take for blocks to propagate?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10821/how-long-does-it-take-to-propagate-a-newly-created-block-to-the-entire-bitcoin-n)
- ["Information and Propagation in the Bitcoin network"](http://www.tik.ee.ethz.ch/file/49318d3f56c1d525aabf7fda78b23fc0/P2P2013_041.pdf), by Decker and Wattenhofer.

Answer (score 1):

Gavin Andresen wrote a bit on the topic here: [O(1) Block Propagation](https://gist.github.com/gavinandresen/e20c3b5a1d4b97f79ac2).

Essentially, he is implementing the conclusion from [your answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30480/5406), a way to get around resending all transactions when propagating a new block. He is working on implementing [Invertible Bloom Lookup Tables](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/30648/5406) to use for set reconciliation. IBLT excel at comparing sets of significant overlap, and therefore are very efficient at relaying the differences between included transactions and Mempool of recipient.