# The ratio between propagation delay and block interval

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory

Is there a certain website or a study that gives an estimation for the 
ratio *f = Propagation Delay/Block Interval* for the Bitcoin network ?
I know the *Block Interval* is roughly 10 minutes however, I don't know the propagation delay. I define it as the time it takes for all nodes to hear  about a mined block after it's been broadcast.

Comment: Probably related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10821/31712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Ethan Heilman [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10821/how-long-does-it-take-to-propagate-a-newly-created-block-to-the-entire-bitcoin-n):

> According the paper 'Information propagation in the bitcoin network.' by Decker and Wattenhofer. The mean time for a node to see a block is 12.6 seconds, after 40 seconds 95% of the nodes have seen that block.

From my personal experience as a developer, this delay is real and noticeable. Some block explorers catch transactions ~20-30 seconds before others. It may be scary at first but its normal.

Comment: This is unrelated. Transaction relay is deliberately slowed down in order to improve privacy (to hide the source of a transaction, random delays are added). This is not the case for block propagation which is very optimized to be as fast as possible.

Comment: He asked about propagation times.

Comment: I assume he means propagation time of blocks. Transaction relay time is not relevant for network convergance. But you're right, it is a guess.