# Is mining a fair mechanism in blockchain network?

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, hashpower

As we know, propagation of a new block in blockchain network has some delay and many nodes receive the new block later. so if it is that the first one who finds the nonce properly wins the block can we say that the mechanism of mining is not fair enough (**Because of delay in propagation of a block some blocks receive the block sooner and have more time to calculate the nonce**)?

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning in your question.

Comment: I edited the question and added the bold sentence to explain the reasoning. @PieterWuille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that a block is mined on [average every 10 minutes](https://www.blockchain.com/fr/explorer) and that the average time to propagate to all nodes is [12.6 seconds](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10821/how-long-does-it-take-to-propagate-a-newly-created-block-to-the-entire-bitcoin-n), I think it is pretty fair.

We could also guess that the big miner have incentives to get the newly mined hash very fast so it must be lower than 12.6 for them.

Comment: so you mean 12.6 seconds in proportion to 10 minutest is not very much and can be negligible?

Comment: @ShakibaZar Yes, and for the ones that really care it is lower than 12.6 seconds

Comment: how it can be lower than 12.6 for the ones who care? do they have any role in choosing when to receive the block?

Comment: @ShakibaZar big miners have resources so they can use Satellite internet for example, which will tell them about the new valid block very fast no matter on which continent it happened