# How often do double spends happen successfully?

Tags: doublespend

Judging from this list, not very often:

https://blockchain.info/double-spends

Why is this the case? I would have guessed they would have been more frequent.

Is it OK to always accept (small-to-medium) transactions as valid then?

Answer (score 1):

The [wiki explains it better than I can](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Double-spending):

But the short answer is that's the reason most participants [wait for at least 6 confirmations](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Confirmation) before accepting a transaction as valid.  The likelihood of hash collisions or other potential attacks having any success going undetected drops with each confirmation, and 6 confirmations is usually chosen as an "overkill" number.

To answer your question from the post title, though, refer to this question's answers:

[Has there ever been a successful double spend attack on the Bitcoin network? If not, is it really necessary to wait for confirmations?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/722/has-there-ever-been-a-successful-double-spend-attack-on-the-bitcoin-network-if?rq=1)

If what they say is correct, it seems we really don't know if and when (or how often) any double-spends have actually been successful.